# Is there a default display format for wtforms DateField / DateTimeField?

Tags: date, datetime, flask, wtforms

With Python3, Flask, Jinja and WTForms I'm building a WEB form.

In my FlaskForm I have two DateFields:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import DateField, DateTimeField
from wtforms.validators import Optional

class FormPerson(FlaskForm):
    birthday = DateField('Birthday', name='birthday', validators=[Optional()])
    changed = DateTimeField('Changed', name='changed', render_kw={'readonly': True}, validators=[Optional()])
```

I'm a bit confused about the behavior of these two fields:

Rendering this as `{{ FormPerson.birthday }}` resp. `{{ FormPerson.changed }}` ends up with `birthday` as a datepicker (as I had expected), showing the birthday in the format `%d.%m.%Y`, while `changed` comes to a StringField (not a datetimepicker as i had expected), showing the `changed` in the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.

The display format in the `DateTimeField` I can manipulate by passing `format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S`, the `DateField` I can't, in fact it doesn't work if I try.

Is there any default format for both of these fields? May be depending of some language/country settings in the browser, the webserver or the location the user is sitting (in my case it's Germany?

And why is there a datepicker but not a datetimepicker?

Any hint is wellcome!

Comment: By the way: it could even be better not to pass a format string to the `DateField` nor to the `DateTimeField`. But that would make it necessary that both use the common local format. The `DateField` seems to do that, `DateTimeField` doesn't.